# Why this state variable is not incremented in real time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand react.js and I have this code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        variable : 12,
    }
    state1 = () => "Hello"
    state3 = {
        variable3 : 1,
    }
    varia = () => { this.setState((old, pr) => {
        return {
            variable3 : old.variable3+1
        }
    });
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.timer = setInterval(() => this.varia(), 1000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    render(){
        return (<>
        <div>{this.state.variable}</div>
        <div>{this.state3.variable3}</div>
        </>);
    }
}

export default App;
```

This code doesn't work whereas the following code works like a charm :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        variable : 12,
    }
    state1 = () => "Hello"
    state3 = {
        variable3 : 1,
    }
    varia = () => { this.setState((old, pr) => {
        return {
            variable : old.variable+1
        }
    });
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.timer = setInterval(() => this.varia(), 1000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    render(){
        return (<>
        <div>{this.state.variable}</div>
        <div>{this.state3.variable3}</div>
        </>);
    }
}

export default App;
```

Do you know why I in the first case it does not work ? I mean I have to use state instead of state3 ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: in class component you have one state named state. useState setting state of variable state, no any state like state 1, state 3.

Comment: if you need to store value in some other varialbe like state2... you can set value of state2 "manualy"  this.satte2.value = "somting" and then make this.forceUpdate()... but this is not recommended

Comment: Ok so I must to have a one state named state to update the variable ?

Comment: correct is only one state. this.setSatate work on this.state.... and using this.setState forces rendering is  state is changed

Answer (score 0):

`variable3` does not exist on `state`, it exists on `state3`, so when you try to access it with `variable3 : old.variable3+1`, it isn't a property on `old`, so you're essentially doing `undefined + 1`

One thing to note is that `state` is a special name in a React component, so your component will re-render when `state` changes but NOT when `state3` changes.